# .zip file in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to play around with Android development.
While trying to install Android SDK, I can see the SDK being in .zip format.
Does .zip file is a valid archive format for Ubuntu ?.

http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729.zip

Comment: After downloading the file, you can right click on it and see several "extract" options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file-roller, which is the default archive manager for Ubuntu, supports the .zip format as well as many other formats.

File-roller supports the following formats:
• Tar (.tar) archives, including those compressed with
    gzip (.tar.gz, .tgz), bzip (.tar.bz, .tbz), bzip2 (.tar.bz2, .tbz2),
    compress (.tar.Z, .taz), lzip (.tar.lz, .tlz), lzop (.tar.lzo, .tzo),
    lzma (.tar.lzma) and xz (.tar.xz)
• Zip archives (.zip)
• Jar archives (.jar, .ear, .war)
• 7z archives (.7z)
• iso9660 CD images (.iso)
• Lha archives (.lzh)
• Single files compressed with gzip (.gz), bzip (.bz), bzip2 (.bz2),
    compress (.Z), lzip (.lz), lzop (.lzo), lzma (.lzma) and xz (.xz)

If you want to install the Android SDK ADT Bundle, you should also take a look at the software dependencies for the Android SDK ADT Bundle which you can find on the [Get the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) webpage by clicking on the gray arrow next to SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS.